# .NET 3.5 and 4 compatible exe

Tags: .net

Is it possible to create a single-file exe application that runs on .NET 3.5 and 4, whichever is installed?

I know I can make my .NET 3.5 app run on 4.x by supplying an additional `.exe.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" /> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> 
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Can I embed this information in my `.exe` file instead?

Registry modifications are not an option.

Edit: since there are claims that it "just works", here is a minimal example:

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

compiled with:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc hello.cs
```

when run on a Windows 8 without .NET 3.5, it prompts to install .NET 3.5. I would like to avoid this prompt and run on any newer .NET Framework available.

Comment: Just build your program targeting .NET 3.5 and it should be fine either way (at least for the vast majority of code).

Comment: On a fresh Windows 8 installation it prompts me to install .NET 3.5...

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I would have expected that to work...

Comment: Poor man's answer: https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme/blob/master/IronScheme/IronScheme.Console/genv4.cmd :p

Comment: The config file is required to convince the CLR that you know what you're doing and have tested your app to work properly on a .NET version it was not built to target.  Microsoft did take the opportunity at 4.0 to fix several old bugs that could not be fixed without risking breaking existing programs.  Time to retire 3.5 btw.